# Trying to initialize FullPage.JS after scrolling through hero

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

Trying to initiate FullPage.JS after scrolling through hero. Right now if you scroll past the hero - FullPage gets initialized and continues to scroll through the slides with the momentum of the initial scroll. I have this function inplace for my init.

```
function initFullPage(){
  $(".view-case-study").addClass("projects-load");
  $(".pagination").addClass("visible");
  $(".logo-menu svg").toggleClass("hovered");

  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    lazyLoading:false,
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    css3:true,
    normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,
    touchSensitivity: 10,
    anchors: a_anchors,
    menu: '#myMenu',
    normalScrollElements: '.nav, .open-nav, .project-inner, .work-mode, .menu-shelf, .tab, .view-case-study, #hero, .hero-center-container',
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){  
    var loadedSection = $(this);
    projectUrl = loadedSection.data('url');
    project_title = loadedSection.data('title');
    loadedSection.addClass('projects-load');
    loadedSection.find(".full-line").animate({'width':'100%'},500);
    loadedSection.animate({'background-position-y':'-20px','background-size':'120%'},1000);
    $('#hero').animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
    $('#hero').addClass('destroy');
    $('.ui-info').animate({'opacity':'1'},350);
    },
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    var leavingSection = $(this);
    leavingSection.removeClass('projects-load');
    leavingSection.find(".full-line").animate({'width':'0%'},250); 
    leavingSection.animate({'background-position-y':'0px','background-size':'110%'},100);
    $('#project-inner-container').animate({scrollTop:0},0);
    $('.ui-info').animate({'opacity':'0'},0);
    }
  });
fullPageInit = true;
}
```

Below is my Hero scroll script. I've tried to initialize the script and silentmove to the first section but it doesn't want to listen.

```
var winHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function () { 

    var scrTop = $(document).scrollTop() / winHeight, 
        scrTopFixed = scrTop.toFixed(2), 
        scrTransform = scrTopFixed * 80, 
  bgPos = scrTransform / 10 + 95,
  heroOpacity = 1 - scrTransform / 100;

if ((scrTransform >= 80) && (fullPageInit == false)) {
  initFullPage();
  $.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('#sidepocket');
}

    $('svg.scroll-end').css({
        'clip': "rect(0px," + scrTransform + "px,200px,0px)",
    });

}); // Close
```

Comment: Why not creating a section for the hero?

Comment: In your example http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html the scroll momentum still carries over to the next section. 
If you scroll fast it continues to scroll past the current slide. I also want the scroll svg to fill like it is before removing/destroying itself and bringing in section-01

Comment: Is your hero using scroll bar?

Comment: @Alvaro The scroll bar is hidden, but it's using the default web scroll function to fill in the svg centered bottom of the hero.

Comment: @Alvaro I got it finally!

Comment: Awesome! Congrats!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Scroll SVG Hero

  $('#scroll-control').on('scroll',function(e){
    var totalScroll = $('#scroll-control').scrollTop();
    var slowScroll = totalScroll * .2;
    console.log(slowScroll);
    $('svg.scroll-end').css({
      'clip': "rect(0px," + slowScroll + "px,200px,0px)",
    });
    if(totalScroll > 400){
      if((fullPageInit == false) && (workPage == false)){
        fullPageInit = true;
         $('#hero').animate({'opacity':'0'},300,function(){
           // remove scroll listener
           $('#scroll-control').off();
           // set first project DOM
           var wh = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight:$(window).height();
           $('#fullpage section').height(wh);
           var loadedSection = $('#fullpage section:first-child');
          projectUrl = loadedSection.data('url');
          project_title = loadedSection.data('title');
          loadedSection.addClass('projects-load');
          loadedSection.find(".full-line").animate({'width':'100%'},500);
           history.pushState(null, null, '#'+projectUrl);
          loadedSection.animate({'background-position-y':'-20px','background-size':'120%'},1000,function(){
            initFullPage();
            $('#scroll-control').hide();
            });

          $('.ui-info').animate({'opacity':'1'},350);
         });
          $('#hero').addClass('destroy');
      }
    }
  });

    var winHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        console.log(e);
        var scrTop = $(document).scrollTop() / winHeight, 
            scrTopFixed = scrTop.toFixed(2), 
            scrTransform = scrTopFixed * 80, 
      bgPos = scrTransform / 10 + 95,
      heroOpacity = 1 - scrTransform / 100;
    if ((scrTransform >= 80) && (fullPageInit === false)) {
    }

    }); // Close
```

The issue was fixed by setting a time out so that FullPage doesn't initialize until the scrolling of the mouse ends, therefore you do not overscroll or have any momentum that forces the user to the next section.

Hope this helps others trying to build custom scripts into FullPage.JS

https://www.alexcoven.com